# Show that the function $z \mapsto(f\circ g)(z)$ is complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that if $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $g:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ are analytic  then the function $z \mapsto f(g(z))$ is complex differentiable.

My Attempt :

consider $(fog)'(z_o)=\lim _{z\rightarrow z_o} \frac{f(g(z)-f(g(z_o))}{z-z_o}\\
\lim _{z\rightarrow z_o} \frac{f(g(z)-f(g(z_o))}{g(z)-g(z_o)} \times \lim _{z\rightarrow z_o } \frac{g(z)-g(z_o)}{z-z_o}$

is i am right if right what is the next can any one help me

Comment: Do you know about the chain rule?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff...(fog)'=f'(g(x)) g'(x) yes i know this is the chain rule

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff:  that's what we're being asked to prove, right?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff..thanks i need help from where i stuck as i attempted

Comment: @Robert Lewis.. i need help from where i stuck as i attempted

Comment: as $g$ is analytic you can change $z\rightarrow z_0$ to $g(z)\rightarrow g(z_0)$ in the first limit.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on the right track.

Since $f$ is analytic at $g(z_0)$ and $g$ is analytic at $z_0$, the two limits of your equation exists and hence $$\lim \frac{f\circ g(z)-f\circ g(z_0)}{z-z_0} \qquad \text{exists},$$ and so $f\circ g$ is analytic at $z_0$.

This is the chain rule.